# Having Trouble With POST Bodies in Javascript (window.fetch)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using HTML5 and javascript but I could not make a POST request to a URL with a body. The code I used is:

```
var username = document.getElementById('uname').value;
var password = document.getElementById('pword').value;
var rbody = JSON.stringify({username, password});
window.fetch('https://somewhere.com/some/path', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: rbody
})
.then(res=> {
    console.log(res.body);
    return res.text()
}).then(res=> {
    if(res === 'true') {
        window.localStorage.setItem('loginDetails', {
            username,
            password
        });
        window.location = "https://somewhere.com/home";
    }
    else alert('Girdiğiniz kullanıcı ismi ya da şifre yanlış.');
});
```

The requests' bodies were empty. I couldn't make a request with a body :(

Thanks for your helps in advance.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?  Can you post the response you got?

Comment: @MattMorgan it always responses with false. Even if password and username is right

Comment: also, the request url is in the same domain. I logged request.body.password and it logged undefined. And I think this means the body is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for help guys, but none of them worked for me. I searched more and found $.ajax (jquery) Now I'm using $.ajax and it's working fine.
Here is the code I used (I added form):

```
$.ajax({
    url:'/api/checkpassword',
    type:'post',
    data:$('#logInForm').serialize(),
    success:function(res){
        if(res === 'true' || res === true) {
          window.localStorage.setItem('loginDetails', {username: document.getElementById('uname').value, password:document.getElementById('pword').value});
          window.location = "https://dchat.glitch.me/home";
        }
        else alert('Girdiğiniz kullanıcı ismi ya da şifre yanlış.');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just run your code like this and it worked:

```
var username = 'username';
var password = 'password';
var rbody = JSON.stringify({username, password});
window.fetch('https://somewhere.com/some/path', {method: 'POST', body: rbody}).then(res=> {console.log(res.body);  return res.text()}).then(res=> {
  if(res === 'true') {
    window.localStorage.setItem('loginDetails', {username, password});
    window.location = "https://somewhere.com/home";
  }
  else alert('Girdiğiniz kullanıcı ismi ya da şifre yanlış.');
});
```

Open Developer Tools, check 'Preserve Log' option on 'Network' tab and run it on Console. Then go back to 'Network' tab and check the request (Headers tab, Request Payload). The body is sent.

Comment: How can i check the body is sent

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with the way you are making the request, but I think the back end is not sending proper data or there is some error. You can open the console and in the network tab, you can see the request is going properly. you can also see the response returned there.

One thing that you are not doing though is checking for errors

```
var username = document.getElementById('uname').value;
var password = document.getElementById('pword').value;
var rbody = JSON.stringify({ username, password });
window
    .fetch('https://somewhere.com/some/path', { method: 'POST', body: rbody })
    .then(res => {
        if(!res.ok)
            return Promise.reject(new Error(response.statusText));
        return res.text()
    })
    .then(res => {
        if (res === 'true') {
            window.localStorage.setItem('loginDetails', { username, password });
            window.location = "https://somewhere.com/home";
        }
        else alert('Girdiğiniz kullanıcı ismi ya da şifre yanlış.');
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        //handle errors here
        console.log(err);
    });
```

Comment: no errors. when I try to do it with form it works successfully but it redirects to the URL and I don't want it

Comment: Can you Open the inspector inside your browser (cmd + shift + i) and switch to the network tab and share what the response is coming from the server?